# Fastest way Store data in database using c#

Tags: c#, database, performance, store

I have a csv file with 3 million lines and want to stored it in a database using c#. The csv file looks like "device;date;value".

Shall I write it into an array or directly into a System.Data.DataTable? And what is the fastest way to store this DataTable into a Database (SQL-Server for example).

I tried to store the lines using 3 million insert into statements but it was too slow :)

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to load data from text file then store it into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969812/fastest-way-to-load-data-from-text-file-then-store-it-into-database)

Comment: Is this a one-off operation or do you need to do it repeatedly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the data in a DataTable and then use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) for copying the date to the table in sql server

> The SqlBulkCopy class can be used to write data only to SQL Server
>   tables. However, the data source is not limited to SQL Server; any
>   data source can be used, as long as the data can be loaded to a
>   DataTable instance or read with a IDataReader instance.
>   .

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) would be pretty fast. Once you have the data in a DataTable you can try

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bcp= new SqlBulkCopy(yourConnectionString))
{
    BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TargetTable";
    BulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to open stream reader and create row line by line. Use ReadLine in a while loop and split to find differents parts.

Answer (score 0):

Sending 3 millions insert statements is bordering on crazy slow!

Buffer it by using transactions and reading in for example 200-1000 lines at a time (the smaller your data, the more you can read in at a time) then, after reading in these lines,  commit your inserts to the database directly.